# Texmaker creates new document after each run

Tags: texmaker

LaTeX (Texmaker) suddenly creates a new PDF with the name of + the current number.
How can I avoid this?

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,ngerman,reqno,a4paper]{article}


\begin{document}
hallo12345

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide your software version and operational system? Maybe it's some specific settings.

Comment: I'm using macOS Ventura 13.3.1 (a) and Texmaker 5.1.4. It doesn't happen, when I create a new tex document. But when I work on my master thesis, suddenly texmaker creates multiple pdfs and even when I change it to the previous code this happens.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I do not think that this has anything to do with your code. Did you try to compile from the command line as well? I'd rather think that somehow you changed the settings in TeXmaker (which is only the editor), so that it calls LaTeX with some setting that leads to the numbered file name.

Comment: It works normally with the command line. So I think it has to do with Texmaker. Does anyone have any idea, which settings could effect this?

Comment: Don't use Texmaker, just regular Latex.